# How to check if a 2D array is latin

Tags: java, 2d

I have an assignemnt to check if a 2d array is latin or not.
I made 2 seperate methods, one to check if the array contains duplicates and the other to check if the array is latin using the first method. However for some reason it's returning false for arrays that are latin. Can someone please help me?

```
package car;

public class Car {
    private static boolean isLatin;

    public static boolean isLatin(int[][]array){

        for (int i = 0; i<array.length ;i++) {

            // check for duplicates in each row
            if(duplicates(array[i])) {
                return false;
            }

            // create a column array
            int[] column = new int[array[i].length]; 
            for(int j = 0; j<array[i].length; j++) {

                // check for duplicates in each column
                if(duplicates(column)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public  static boolean duplicates(int[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i<array.length; i++) {
            for(int j = i+1; j<array.length; j++) {
                if ( array[i] == array[j]) {
                    return true;
                }
            }    
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int [][] arr2D={{10,30,20,0},
                        {0,20,30,10},
                        {30,0,10,20},
                        {20,10,0,30} };

        if (isLatin(arr2D))
            System.out.println("Yes, 2D array is a Latin Square");
        else
            System.out.println("NO, 2D array is NOT a Latin Square");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with latin? How is an array that contains no duplicates "latin"?

Comment: I suggest you need a Latin dictionary to determine whether an array contains Latin words. ;-)

Comment: `int[] column = new int[array[i].length];`...  This line doesn't copy your array, you end up with an array filled with `0`'s.  This _will_ contain duplicates so your function returns `false`.  Make that array a copy and you should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is how you're checking your columns.  You're creating an `int[]` named `column`, but you're never adding anything to it.  Which means that all of the `int` elements initialize to their default value of zero.  That means that `column` is always equal to `[0, 0, 0, 0]` (given your test input of a 4x4 array), which of course has duplicates, causing your overall check to always indicate that the matrix is not a Latin Square.

Answer (score 1):

In this section:

```
int[] column = new int[array[i].length]; 
for(int j = 0; j<array[i].length; j++)
{

  // check for duplicates in each column
  if(duplicates(column))
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

The variable column is being instantiated as an int array with no values. So java fills all positions of the array with the default value of *0*. That makes *duplicates(column)* to return true all the time, thus making the function return false all the time.